# jQuery custom function - this.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need some help regarding a jQuery plugin I'm creating.

```
$.fn.mymethod = {
  init : function(options){

      this.each(function() {
          var settings = {  };
          if(options){ $.extend(settings, options); }

      });

      return this;
  }
}

$("input[type=text]").mymethod.init();
```

It doesn't seem to work, I get an error: 
**TypeError: this.each is not a function** on line

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery has a $.each for enumerated objects such as arrays. It also has a .each for jQuery collections. Your `this` is neither an array nor a jQuery collection. You can try $.each(this) to get at methods and other attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do it this way without the extra level of object reference:

```
$.fn.mymethodInit = function(options){

      this.each(function() {
          var settings = {  };
          if(options){ $.extend(settings, options); }

      });

      return this;
}
```

When you interject the extra object in the way as in your original proposal, that means it then has to be called as:

```
$(...).mymethod.init()
```

And, calling it that way, means that the `this` pointer is `mymethod`, not the jQuery object which you need it to be.  This is just a consequence of how Javascript sets the `this` pointer when you call `foo.bar.method()`.

There are some work-arounds, but all are generally ugly and complicated so just give up the extra level of the dot syntax.  A common work-around is to just use a common prefix on all your methods:

```
$.fn.mymethod_Init = function() {...}
$.fn.mymethod_Save = function() {...}
```

which is just as unique a namespace as you were attempting to use, but does not create the problem you ran into.

Comment: You do not need `)};` at the end